# Prevent scanner from freezing program

Tags: c#

I'm currently developing a module where a user can scan documents and save them. currently, the working code that is being used is from **Jeske**, from GitHub (link is [here](https://github.com/jeske/WIADemo/blob/master/WIADemo/WIAScanner.cs)). The scanner that the customer is using is : **Epson Perfection V600**. The earlier mentioned code is working like a charm, expect for 1 situation: If the scanner goes into sleep/inactive mode and the user tries to scan a document while in that state, the application will freeze itself while waiting for the scanner to respond ( sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't). To be exact, the program freezes at this particular line:

```
WIA.ImageFile image = (WIA.ImageFile)wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item, wiaFormatBMP, false);
```

My question is: is there a way to prevent the application from freezing while trying to scan from the given scanner?(This issue only happens when scanner is in sleep/inactive mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use concurrency to prevent blocking. If you also use CancellationToken with CancellationTokenSource whenever the operation does not ends, you can send cancel signal to your funtion so the scanning operation will be aborted.

```
public Task Scan()
{
    ....
    WIA.ImageFile image = (WIA.ImageFile)wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item, wiaFormatBMP, false);
    ...
}
```

then in your main program

```
//wait 20 seconds before cancellation
CancellationTokenSource cts=  new CancellationTokenSource(20000);
var myTask = Task.Run(() => Scan(),  cts.Token);
await myTask;
```

Comment: **... as long as `wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer` may be called from different than UI thread ...** which I doubt ... did you test it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that (`wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer `) has got to be on the UI thread.  That's probably not going to work.  The fact that the freezing is happening in someone else's code (running on the UI thread) doesn't make this look like an easy thing to solve

Answer (score 0):

I used TWIN protocol, instead of WIA, for scanning, and solved hanging successfully. You can get the best TWAIN library from here:
https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner